# How to build something targeting netstandard framework?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to build something, specifically NuGet's github repo, and I keep getting an error on my project.json files saying "netstandard 1.5 is an unsupported framework."  I haven't used .net core much at all yet, but I can run dnx fine yeI can't at all figure out how to run this.  I found only 1 question on stack overflow stating that tooling for visual studio is not available for netstandard.  What exactly then do you need to build this?  dnu restore gives the same error.

FYI, I am on RC1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`netstandard` is reserved for RC2. Wait for a few days and RC2 will be available.

Answer (score 0):

Use the build.ps1 script in the NuGet.Client repo to build. It downloads dotnet CLI (https://github.com/dotnet/cli) and uses it to restore and build the netstandard projects.